# How to write to a SQLite database using Polars in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-polars

```py
import polars as pl
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
df = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3]})
```

According to the documentation of [`pl.write_database`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_database.html), I need to pass a connection URI string e.g. "sqlite:////path/to/database.db" for SQLite database:

```py
df.write_database("test_table", f"sqlite:////test.db", if_table_exists="replace")
```

However, I got the following error:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
```

EDIT: Based on the answer, install SQLAlchemy with the `pip install polars[sqlalchemy]` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with SQLite, the number of slashes depends on how you are accessing the sqlite file.  If you use two slashes as suggested in the comments, you'll see this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Invalid SQLite URL: sqlite://test.db
Valid SQLite URL forms are:
 sqlite:///:memory: (or, sqlite://)
 sqlite:///relative/path/to/file.db
 sqlite:////absolute/path/to/file.db
```

It appears that in your case, you want to use 3 slashes and not 4.  Please try this instead:

```
df.write_database("test_table", f"sqlite:///test.db", if_table_exists="replace")
```

This would be a working example, based on the sample code snippets you provided:

```
import polars as pl
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
df = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3]})
df.write_database("test_table", f"sqlite:///test.db", if_table_exists="replace")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for writing / reading sqlite tables using polars.

**Write table to database** (*sqlalchemy* needs to be installed)**.**

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})

df.write_database(
    "my_table",
    connection="sqlite:///database.db",
    if_table_exists="replace"
)
```

**Read table from database** (*connectorx* needs to be installed)**.**

```py
pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT * FROM my_table", uri="sqlite://database.db")
```

Note the format of the connection URI.

- sqlite:///:memory: (or, sqlite://)
- sqlite:///relative/path/to/file.db
- sqlite:////absolute/path/to/file.db
- sqlite:///c:/absolute/path/on/windows/file.db (credit to @Thomas)

Comment: Just to complete your answer... If you have an absolute path using Windows: `sqlite:///c:/path/to/file.db`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I've updated the answer (giving you credit ofc!)

Comment: So basically the problem was that I was using four slash (////) instead of three. I misunderstood the documentation, thanks for the clarification!